# Calling a DLL function with more than one return values

Tags: delphi, dll

My DLL might send more than one result/return value to exe in one shoot. I still don't understand how to make the callback function so DLL can communicate with host app.

Here's the scenario :

App :

```
type
  TCheckFile = function(const Filename, var Info, Status: string): Boolean; stdcall;

var
  CheckFile: TCheckFile;
  DLLHandle: THandle;

Procedure Test;
var
Info,Status : string;
begin
....
// load the DLL 
DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('test.dll');
    if DLLHandle <> 0 then
    begin
      @CheckFile := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'CheckFile');
      if Assigned(CheckFile) then
        beep
      else
        exit;
    end;

// use the function from DLL
if Assigned(CheckFile) then
  begin
    if CheckFile(Filename, Info, Status) then
    begin
    AddtoListView(Filename, Info, Status);
    end;
  end;
...
end;
```

DLL:

```
function CheckFile(const Filename, var Info,Status: string): Boolean; stdcall;
  var
    Info, Status: string;
  begin   
    if IsTheRightFile(Filename, Info,Status) then
    begin
      result := true;
      exit;
    end
    else
    begin
      if IsZipFile then
      begin
        // call function to extract the file
        ExtractZip(Filaname);
        // check all extracted file
        for i := 0 to ExtractedFileList.count do
        begin
          IsTheRightFile(ExtractedFile, Info, Status) then
          // how to send the Filename, Info and Status to exe ?? // << edited
          // SendIpcMessage('checkengine', pchar('◦test'), length('◦test') * SizeOf(char)); error!
          // "AddtoListView(Filename, Info);" ???
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Actually I still get an error from code above. So in my case, I need your help to explain and determine what is the correct way to send data from DLL to appp.

Comment: GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'CheckFile'); - does it return a valid handle? did not you forget to specify your dll funciton in IMPORTS section?

Comment: Do you mean `Info` and `Status` instead of `Info` and `Filename`? Because `Filename` is `const` and can not be modiefied. To modify `Info` and `Status` you would need to set a value for it in your DLL function. Be aware that passing around strings can lead to problems if you do not use `ShareMem` in the `uses` clause.

Comment: @heximal : Yes it return a valid handle. I am sure there is no problem with importing/exporting function. I have tried to use dummy function in DLL.

Comment: @ba__friend. Hmm.. I use FastMM because I want non-Delphi exe can use my DLL.

Comment: Does your code really contains a function with the `Info` & `Status` formal parameters *and* the `Info` & `Status` local variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right lines but the most obvious problem that I can see is the use of `string` variables. These are heap allocated and since you have two separate memory managers you will be allocating on one heap (in the DLL) and then freeing on a different heap (in the app).

There are a few options.  One options would be to share memory managers but I don't recommend this for a variety of reasons.  Without going into them you state in a comment that you want non Delphi applications to be able to use your DLL which would preclude the use of a shared memory manager.

Another option would be to force the calling app to allocate the memory for the string and then let your DLL copy into that memory.  This works fine but is somewhat labour intensive.

Instead I would use a string type which can be allocated in one module but freed in a different module.  The COM `BSTR` is such a type and in Delphi terms this is `WideString`.  Change the code to use `WideString` for any exported functions.

---

I would also simplify the importing/exporting process and use implicit dynamic linking.

**DLL**

```
function CheckFile(
  const Filename: WideString; 
  var Info, Status: WideString
): Boolean; stdcall;
```

**App**

```
function CheckFile(
  const Filename: WideString; 
  var Info, Status: WideString
): Boolean; stdcall; external 'test.dll';

procedure Test(const FileName: string);
var
  Info, Status: WideString;
begin
  if CheckFile(Filename, Info, Status) then
    AddtoListView(Filename, Info);
end;
```

Comment: I use FastMM. Do I still need to concern about it?

Comment: @user Indeed you do since you will have two instance of the FastMM allocator.  Whilst you can share memory managers, what about any other potential clients of your DLL?  I strongly recommend avoiding exporting memory allocated by a private allocator.  You can do it with WideString since it relies on the shared COM allocator.

Comment: In my case, I need a static linking. I'll try WideString. In my opinion I just have to use WideString for the exported parameters(=string) and it is okay to use string in other function, right? Playing in DLL is a new stuff for me.

Comment: DLL=Dynamic Linking. What do you mean "I need a static linking"?

Comment: @Cosmin, Sorry I read this http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0130.htm and from that link, I need to use dynamic method.

Comment: @user Don't use string at the boundary of a DLL.  Non Delphi clients can't call the function and different Delphi versions could fail too.  Use `WideString` or `PChar`.

Comment: @David Using WideString then it's working now! But is it possible with one function call from App then the DLL could send many return value to App? If yes, please give me the clue, what kind of method that should I use? Thanks.

Comment: @user Are you wanting to send back an array of strings?  If so then I'd regard that as a new question.  I don't want to try and answer that in comments to this question (which I think has been answered now).

Comment: @David With array of strings, the DLL have to do all operations until the completion then it send back to App. In my case, is it possible DLL use IPC for sending some data to App? Yes or no? Thanks.

Comment: It's possible in a DLL in a variety of ways.  You could use double-zero terminated strings.  Or you could use linebreak terminated with a TStringList if your strings don't have line breaks.  It's worth another question though!